# Azure Automated machine learning

Tags: azure

Hey I am working on learning azure and I have run into a problem. I have been following a guide and then I get this error:
"The provided time column Year contains pd.NaT which may be a result of some data points not fitting the expected time format to start training. To continue, please reformat the time stamp to the supported month-day-year format and try again."

This is my code I am using python and jupyter notebook in vscode:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('vgsales.csv')
df.head(9)

X = df.select_dtypes(include=[object])
X.head(3)

from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
X = X.apply(le.fit_transform)
X = X.drop(columns=['Name'])
X.head(3)

y = df.drop(columns=['Rank','Name', 'Platform', 'Year', 'Genre', 'Publisher'])
y

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)

model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

score = model.score(X_test,y_test)
score

import joblib

joblib.dump(model,'output-model.joblib')

model = joblib.load('output-model.joblib')
```

[[[[[enter image description here]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlsBE.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/e63Yi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzmor.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDFYt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYm8V.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L32tE.png)

Comment: nevermind Im stupid, I wasn't training it as a regression model i was using time forecast, I didn't realise that it was selecting it as an option, I thought that it was just a page that I had to put all the data into lol

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information, the provided python code is for `Regression Task` and with you are selecting `Time Series Forecasting Task` during task selection.

To fix this the issue you can select the `Regression` in `Task selection page`.

[image]

For more detail, you can check [AutoML training with the studio UI.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-automated-ml-for-ml-models?view=azureml-api-2)